# "Haben" oder "Hat" soll ich benuzten, wenn es mit "etwas" ist

Tags: grammaticality

Ich habe eine Frage, ob ich "Haben" oder "Hat" benutzen soll.

> Gestern ***haben*** etwas Dramatisches passiert.

Ich weiße nicht, dass "Dramatisches" plural ist oder nicht.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zuerst einmal: Das Verb [*passieren*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/passieren) hat mehrere Bedeutungen. Wenn es im Sinne von *durchqueren* oder *an etwas vorbeigehen* verwendet wird, dann ist das Hilfsverb [*haben*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/haben) richtig. Wenn es aber im Sinne von *geschehen* verwendet wird, dann ist das Hilfsverb [*sein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein#Verb,_Hilfsverb) richtig.

In Ihrem Beispiel wird *passieren* im Sinne von *geschehen* verwendet. Daher bleibt die Frage, ob es

- *etwas Dramatisches ist passiert* (Singular)

oder

- *etwas Dramatisches sind passiert* (Plural)

heißen muss. Das wird allein durch das Indefinitpronomen [*etwas*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas) bestimmt, das immer auf etwas [Unbestimmtes *im Singular (Neutrum)*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen#Indefinitpronomina_im_engeren_Sinne) referenziert. Die [3. Person Singular von *sein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sein#Indikativ_und_Konjunktiv) lautet *ist*, und deshalb heißt es:

> Gestern *ist etwas Dramatisches* passiert.

Comment: Gute Beobachtung, dass es auch ein transitives Passieren gibt.

Comment: Wobei man auch zB. [die Äpfel passiert haben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passieren?wprov=sfla1) kann...

Answer (score 1):

*Dramatisches* ist Singular (ich würde es als unzählbar betrachten), *etwas Dramatisches* auch. Das richtige Hilfsverb zu passieren ist aber *sein*.

> Gestern ist etwas Dramatisches passiert.